# get sum of all entries by column in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

So I have table `prices` with structure:

```
+----+--------+
| id | reward |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 721    |
+----+--------+
| 2  | 54     |
+----+--------+
| 3  | 99     |
+----+--------+
```

and I'm using this method to sum all rewards:

```
'withdrawals' => \App\Tradeoffer::where('type', 'withdraw')
            ->where('completed', 1)
            ->where('declined', 0)
            ->where('timeout', 0)
            ->where('created_at', '>', (time() - $hours))
            ->sum('reward')
```

and the response is: 7215499 instead of sum of all entries. Why is that? How to deal with it?

Comment: Well, are these things strings or numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like,

```
$totalReward = \App\Tradeoffer::selectRaw('SUM(reward) as total')
        ->where('type', 'withdraw')
        ->where('completed', 1)
        ->where('declined', 0)
        ->where('timeout', 0)
        ->where('created_at', '>', (time() - $hours))
        ->first();

$totalReward->total;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use the model I use a Query Builder and it works (with my database)

```
DB::table('Tradeoffer') // Here is the name of the table
    ->where('type', 'withdraw')
    ->where('completed', 1)
    ->where('declined', 0)
    ->where('timeout', 0)
    ->where('created_at', '>', (time() - $hours))
    ->sum('reward');
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is making sure your `reward` column in `prices` table in database is number (integer/float) and not `varchar`

Comment: What result do you get when you run in MYSQL: `SELECT sum(reward) FROM prices WHERE type='withdraw' AND completed=1 AND declined=0 AND timeout=0` ?

Comment: @ArnasPecelis In what table you verified it's int(11)? Your `prices` table structure is different than columns used for `Tradeoffer`

Comment: the problem was with date... it was not timestamp, it was date.

Comment: Ok, but doest it make any difference to `sum`? It should sum anyway if there are any records found